# Symmetric mod game

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

$N$ is a big integer value, with only two non trivial factors.

Value $k$ will be `Symmetric mod` if and only if, all the possible nontrivial factors of $N$ will be equal mod k.

For example for N = $557*677=377089$ the values 3,4 and 6 are `Symmetric mod`

- $557 \mod 3 = 677 \mod 3 = 2$
- $557 \mod 4 = 677 \mod 4 = 1$
- $557 \mod 6 = 677 \mod 6 = 5$

I thought that in order to check if value is `Symmetric mod`, you do not need to factor $N$, you just need to solve:

$$(a\mod k)(b\mod k) = N \mod k$$

How ever for $k = 5$, the possible options are:

- $a \equiv b \equiv 2(\mod 5)$
- $a \equiv b \equiv 3(\mod 5)$
- $a \equiv 1(\mod 5), b \equiv 4(\mod 5)$

And only after factoring you come to conclusion that $5$ is indeed `Symmetric mod`

- $557 \mod 5 = 677 \mod 5 = 2$

---

How to determinate if $k$ is `Symmetric mod` without factoring $N$?

Comment: I'm not sure your statement "you just need to solve" is correct. For example $(3\mod 3)(7\mod 3)=(21\mod 3)$ but $k=3$ is not a Symmetric mod. Or $(3\mod 4)(7\mod 4)\equiv (23\mod 4)$ but $3\cdot 7\neq 23$. In other words you really do need to know the factors of $N$.

Comment: @AlexR. I think it will not work when you are pick $k$ that is a factor of $N$

Comment: the way I read your statement is that you don't need to know the factors of $N$, so how would you know you picked its factor?

Comment: @AlexR. I edit the question